# Attach specific action to specific part of code

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have a new application that contains great amount of `try-catch` blocks. I am interested in if it is possible to write code which somehow attachs `SaveExceptionInDatabase` method to every `catch`-block I have used in my application.

```
try
{
    //some actions
}
catch(exception e)
{
   SaveExceptionInDatabase(e,DateTime.now(),CurrentUser);
   ShowFriendlyNotification();
}
```

I think it will be helpful to easily remove bugs from my application, because I have noticed for several times that after the exception is thrown, attempting to perform the same operation second time finishes with success.

EDIT:

I am using WPF With Caliburn.Micro

Comment: This is best handled by a general exception logger. You haven't mentioned which framework you are using, but nearly all of them have some pattern for this. You typically catch exceptions that you intend to handle, hence negating the need to log them. If performing the operation twice fixes some issues, then add retry logic.

Comment: I am interested in if I can do it programmatically. If I decide later to change the number of parameters of this method, I will be able to do it in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PostSharp and handle the exceptions.  Here are some related articles that show how it can be done.  This method seems really cool because you can just add an attribute to  your classes an have the exceptions handled.

```
[DatabaseExceptionWrapper]
```

http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Day-1-e28093-OnExceptionAspect
http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Improve-Exception-Handling-and-Caching-using-PostSharp

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
private void HandleDbException(Action action)
{
    try
    {
        action();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       SaveExceptionInDatabase(e, DateTime.now(), CurrentUser);
       ShowFriendlyNotification();
    }
}
```

And then

```
HandleDbException(() => 
{
    //some actions1
});


HandleDbException(() => 
{
    //some actions2
});

...
```

It won't apply the pattern to each try/catch block in your code but at least avoids repeating the catch block.